# Compiling Android phonegap project using Ant

Tags: android, ant, cordova, compilation

For specific reasons, I have to compile a phonegap/android project using ant tool. The project was created by eclipse, but compiling it and installing it on the device has to happen using ant. I did not run into any problems building native android projects using ant, but when I try the same with phonegap, it wouldnt recognize the library droidgap.

This is expected as phonegap.jar is not added automatically to the build.xml on creation. What I can't figure out on my own is how to link phonegap library to ant build.xml and whether or not that will successfully compile phonegap.

Please help,
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ant will find phonegap.jar (and DroidGap), if you put phonegap.jar in {projectName}/libs

Comment: Fixed mine as well (hence the upvote), but what's the difference between /lib and /libs? I have a /lib with the cordova.jar file there, and if I copy it to /libs it works. Do I need it in both places? Is it the Eclipse ADT plugin vs. ant?

Comment: Now, it's ADT. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17