# Gson NoClassDefFoundError after ADT and SDK Tools update to v17

Tags: android, gson, adt, noclassdeffounderror

Today I updated my ADT and SDK Tools to v17 and my projects using
Google's gson jar library started to throw NoClassDefFoundError.
Here's the logcat output:

```
> 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson 03-22
> 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> com.matriksdata.conn.XRequestHandler.connect(XRequestHandler.java:35)
> 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> com.matriksdata.conn.XRequestHandler.makeRequest(XRequestHandler.java:
> 29) 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> com.matriksdata.bavul.XBaseWithConnectionActivity.makeRequest(XBaseWithConnectionActivity.java:
> 46) 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> com.matriksdata.ui.login.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:
> 36) 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 03-22
> 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:
> 1049) 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:
> 1919) 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:
> 1980) 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122) 03-22
> 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
> 03-22 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-22
> 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-22 12:30:58.941:
> E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340) 03-22
> 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-22
> 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-22 12:30:58.941:
> E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit
> $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 03-22 12:30:58.941:
> E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 03-22
> 12:30:58.941: E/AndroidRuntime(21672):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to Clean the project from eclipse?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I faced a similar problem today.

This fixed it for me:

- Remove all Android Library projects and external jars from the build path.
- Create a folder named 'libs' in your project.
- Place all external .jars in that folder, the ADT should now place them under 'Android Dependencies'.
- Re-import all your previous Android Library projects the normal way.

The issue is that external jars are not placed in the 'libs' folder by default when using Properties - Java Build Path- Add External Jar, instead they are placed under 'Referenced Libraries' instead of 'Android Dependencies' and this causes the NoClassDefFoundError.

Please, check [Dealing with dependencies in Android projects](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) for more details.

Comment: Could you please extend your post explaining how you would link **sources** and **javadoc** with this configuration?

Comment: There are some "how-to" fix sources and javadocs in the comments for this the reported issue:[Link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490)

Answer (score 13):

1. Right click the project, and choose Properties
2. Go to Java Build Path-Order and Export.
3. Tick 'Android Private Libraries'
4. Click Project, Clean

Comment: It helped me and saved my lots of hours

Answer (score 10):

For SDK Tools 17 you need to rename your library project's folder from "lib" to "libs" as suggested [here](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/04/fixing-javalangclassnotfoundexception.html).
Also have a look at [this](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17).

Answer (score 5):

This site has the simplest solution which worked for me, select the library's checkbox under "Order and Export".

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Comment: this fixed it for me, but instead of "cleaning" the project, I had to restart eclipse.

Comment: @CQM, thanks for the comment, for me restarting Eclipse also worked, while cleaning the project did not.

Answer (score 2):

I created a quick post in my blog explaining how to fix those problems. It has to do with libraries and a change they made on how Eclipse manages libraries now. You can check it here if you want: http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/fix-some-problems-with-libraries-in-the-adt-17-plugin-10/

Answer (score 2):

Check order and selects in

```
Project->Properties->Java build path->Order and Export:
```

Order and select:

```
select Google APIs (optional)
select Dependencies
select Android Private Libraries
[-] src
[-] gen
```

And in the tab libraries:

> Dependencies
>   Private libraries (jars in 'libs' directory)
>   Others

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check your gson library in build path. maybe gson libraty aren't not accesible.

Answer (score 0):

This is an official link provided by Android Devs at Google.
Go through the article if you are facing NoClassDefFoundException after 
updating the plugin and/or SDK

https://plus.google.com/115995639636688350464/posts/38o8ZA6xQK4

Answer (score 0):

download the GSON jar and make as class path

Answer (score 0):

I'm using GSON in a library project, so to solve this issue beyond add the GSON jar on build path, I needed declare it on my Library project manifest like as below:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.gson" />
```