# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: how do I fix this error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, noclassdeffounderror

I am developing an Android application which makes use of the Osmdroid maps api. I have added the library as an external jar in my build path and I do not get any errors during compile time. However, upon device deployment I get the following error:

```
03-27 16:18:50.986: E/AndroidRuntime(3306): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint
```

I have done some googgling and it is still a mystery to me.

Here is my IDE configuration.

```
Eclipse: Indigo Release version 2  
Java SDK: 1.6.0_31  
Android SDK: 17
```

Comment: do you deploy the external jar with your application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gson NoClassDefFoundError after ADT and SDK Tools update to v17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to go into Build Path/Order and Export, and check the libs as of SDK 17. Then clean your project.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sastraxi, you were on the money. 1000 thanks.

Comment: I have this problem and tried this and others solutions but nothing worked for me. I'm using ADT 20. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt about you and your project. From my viewpoint, I see you have a good design. But why are you working with Build Path / Order and Export? Honestly I've never gone to that tab from the first day I worked with Eclipse.

To import jar files as libraries, use tab Libraries -> add external Jars.

And I'm sorry I don't know about game programming, this is just a suggestion: make sure your engine fits what Android supports. For example Android doesn't support javax.imageio. If not, the app can be compiled with external jars, but can be crashed in runtime.