# NoClassDefFoundError when using Android Volley

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, android-volley

I am trying to make a network request using android volley library:

```
    StringRequest jsObjRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                Network.getFullUrl("/Account/Login"),
                new Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }, new ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

Network.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

I have included the library in the build path under Projects. And it compiles fine,

But when I run the app I get the following error:

```
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at com.fma.mobileapp.LoginActivity.attemptLogin(LoginActivity.java:173)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at com.fma.mobileapp.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:94)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
08-18 21:57:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(22937):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[EDIT}

I am using latest version of Android SDK

Comment: [updated IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870995/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) [add Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897254/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-how-do-i-fix-this-error) give a look at it..

Comment: Did you add a checkmark (and move it to the top) in the Order and Export tab? See an example here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pVX3I.png

Comment: Added a checkbox and moved it to the top. doesn't seem to help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) we need to define the dependency into the gradle file in Android project's app module:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

you can see the latest versions of Volley [**here**](https://github.com/google/volley/releases).

more information:

[**Transmitting Network Data Using Volley**](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: Not a valid answer anymore. The URL isn't showing anything valuable, just an announcement that you'd switch to Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea i have updated the answer!