# Volley - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have already referred to other answers like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371136/noclassdeffounderror-when-using-android-volley), but still getting the following exception :

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/Volley;

Here are the dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    apply plugin: 'maven'
}
```

As a matter of fact, when I try adding Volley as a dependency, it is never shown in the list of dependencies. Whereas other google libraries are displayed.

**Note** : I have already checked other StackOverFlow links, so please, **only if** you are absolute sure that an answer is correctly working for this, feel free to mark this a duplicate.

Comment: you can download Volley from https://github.com/google/volley and import into your project as a module, in your gradle file, you can try `implementation project(':Module_Volley')` where Module_Volley is my module name for volley lib

Answer (score 1):

Open Command prompt and redirect to your project directory and type this

If you are a Windows user: gradlew.bat clean

if you are a mac user type: ./gradlew clean

Comment: make sure that, you have added maven inside all projects in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

If your targetSdkVersion is between 26 and 28, try adding *uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"* in application tag in AndroidManifest. The second approach is: import volley.jar into your app/lids directory and instead of fetching it from gradle, use your local jar as *implementation files('libs/volley.jar')* in build.gradle in app module