# Getting ClassNotFound Error after updating from ADT 16 to ADT 17

Tags: android

My Application was working fine. But as soon as i updated from ADT 16 to ADT 17 then i am getting this error

```
Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/my/app/MyActivity; (130)
Link of class 'Lcom/my/app/MyActivity;' failed
D/AndroidRuntime(328): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(328): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(328): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MyActivity}:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.app.MyActivity in loader   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.my.app-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(328): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.app.MyActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.my.app-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
E/AndroidRuntime(328):  ... 11 more
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Is your Activity defined in the Manifest file properly?

Comment: Obviously... It was working perfectly just before the update... Do u want me to paste my Manifest also?

Comment: use search option!!! one more question about this and ill start killing people one the street ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17

Comment: @Selvin Can you post it as a answer?

Comment: Did this actually resolve your issue? Selvin posted an answer to resolve NoClassDefFoundError's in external libraries, but your issue seems to be (like mine) with activities within your main application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue occurs because the "lib" folder is renamed to "libs" now by Android People.
And as soon as we place our external jars to this "libs" folder then it will automatically be added to the build path of the application.