# Could not find class after update to android sdk 22

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

```
05-16 10:26:18.267: E/dalvikvm(12692): Could not find class 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder', referenced from method com.test.app.ApplicationRoot.onCreate
05-16 10:26:18.267: W/dalvikvm(12692): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 555 (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder;) in Lcom/test/app/ApplicationRoot;
05-16 10:26:18.267: D/dalvikvm(12692): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0005
05-16 10:26:18.267: D/dalvikvm(12692): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x123f at 0x0b in Lcom/test/app/ApplicationRoot;.onCreate
05-16 10:26:18.267: D/AndroidRuntime(12692): Shutting down VM
05-16 10:26:18.267: W/dalvikvm(12692): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4168f2a0)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at com.test.app.ApplicationRoot.onCreate(ApplicationRoot.java:16)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4251)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
05-16 10:26:18.272: E/AndroidRuntime(12692): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After updated to android sdk version 22 today and update to others sdk library as well, I got this error, it work correctly before the update Any ideas?

Comment: I fixed this by changing order and export Java build path of the project properties. Maybe there are some internal change of the SDK causing the error.

Comment: deja vu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923161/getting-classnotfound-error-after-updating-from-adt-16-to-adt-17?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I checked "Android Private Libraries" on my project only(did not touch the library project it references). It works.

Comment: thnaks man , in my case it is checked : i unchecked it then checked it works ... +1

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea where to find this in android studio?

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse go to:

"Project" -> "Properties" -> "Java Build Properties"

In the "Order and Export" tab I checked "Android Private Libraries" on my project. I also did this for the library project it references. This fixed my class not found errors following upgrading to SDK 22.

Comment: ditto -- found the same thing

Comment: Hi - do you know where to find this setting in android studio?

Answer (score 1):

I had same error after upgrade to SDK 22. Check that "Android Private Libraries" is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more thing:

Before the last update I had manually added all jars in my libs folder to the build path in Eclipse. I needed to remove them from the "Libraries" tab in "Project" -> "Properties" -> "Java Build Path" in order to get everything working.

After removing the particular jars I checked everything in "Order and Export" and now I got it working once more.