# NoClassDefFoundError: org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner

Tags: android

I an trying to read an html page. i used the following link: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/  as an example but I get the following error

```
09-14 11:27:54.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10223): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 11:27:54.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10223): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner
09-14 11:27:54.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10223):    at com.example.htmltest.MainActivity.getBlogStats(MainActivity.java:43)
09-14 11:27:54.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10223):    at com.example.htmltest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
09-14 11:27:54.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10223):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-14 11:27:54.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10223):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-14 11:27:54.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10223):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-14 11:27:54.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10223):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-14 11:27:54.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10223):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this error. any thoughts?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions already relating to the error NoClassDefFound

[NoClassDefFoundError for code in an Java library on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678630/noclassdeffounderror-android)
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after integrating project to windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978490/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-after-integrating-project-to-windows-7)
[Gson NoClassDefFoundError after ADT and SDK Tools update to v17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17)

Have you tried any suggestions from these questions yet?

http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects