# Phonegap 1.4.1 WebIntent plugin Error "Class not found" Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am a newbie to developing in phonegap so I am sorry if this is a obvious answer. This is the last part of my project the only part of it that isnt functioning is the plugin.

I get the message "Failed to send email via Android Intent" and get the following error in logcat "Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.4.1.js:651"

I cannot figure this out, I have been at it for the past day!

I have added the plugin to the plugin.xml

*plugin name="webintent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent"*

I have the correct name space for the WebIntent.java file.

*package borismus.webintent;*

And I have the webintent.js file referenced in my index.html.

Below is the function which uses the plugin.
        function emailxmlfile(){

```
var subject = "Sports Code Xml Edit List" + filedate.toDateString();
var body = "";
if(!window.plugins || !window.plugins.webintent){

    alert('Unable to find webintent plugin');

}else{



var extras={};

extras[WebIntent.EXTRA_SUBJECT] = subject;
extras[WebIntent.EXTRA_TEXT] = body;

 window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
        action: WebIntent.ACTION_SEND,
        type: 'text/plain',
        extras: extras
      }, function() {}, function(e) {alert('Failed to send email via Android Intent');});

}};
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17/9820881#9820881 or download newest phonegap

Comment: What version of phonegap u using?

Comment: I am currently using phonegap 4.1

Comment: I have the same problem with Phonegap 1.7.0.  It passes the string "Class not found" into the error handler (would be bound to 'e' in the example above).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know I might be late, but got your same code working without a minor and subtle change: respect capitalization when adding the plugin details to the .xml file. I mean, you stated this:

```
plugin name="webintent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent"
```

BUT **should read this instead** (watch out for the name!):

```
plugin name="WebIntent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent"
```

the red squiggle in Eclipse goes away once you correct the typo, and the code just works fine so I can invoke the email app from mine.

HTH!

Comment: Might be late for him, but you sure saved me! =D

Answer (score 4):

Usally when you get that message, its that you have missed to add the plugin to plugins.xml

```
<plugin name="WebIntent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Things change a lot faster when dealing with Android apps, too bad most of the documentation doesn't get updated as fast as it should.

I'm using phonegap 2.0.0 and I had to add the plugin configuration to the config.xml file and not inside plugins.xml.

Make sure you're loading phonegap.js (cordova-2.0.0.js in my case), webintent.js and that you have the correct package structure on your src folder (src/com/borismus/webintent/WenIntent.java)

You should be all set then.

Comment: You are the first one who wrote that plugins.xml changed to config.xml... I was really lost until now and was making plugins.xml file myself...tnx

Answer (score 0):

You stated the package is:

```
package borismus.webintent;
```

but defined with:

```
plugin name="webintent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent"
```

You're not missing the "com." on the package declaration?

Comment: also add plugin in res/xml/config.xml
<plugin name="WebIntent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent"/>