# NoClassDefFoundError when project imported to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, apache-commons-lang

I am working on an app which uses Commonslang.jar libraries. I was trying to setup it on a new system with newly installed Eclipse.The project is not showing any error But when I run the project it force closes with NoClassDefFoundError at each point where I use Commonslang lib.

I dont know how to fix this problem.Please help?

Comment: are you using that jar file in one of your Android Library Project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android check this.

Comment: @Waqas Yes I am using jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are **"lib"** folder in your project directory so just change it **"libs"** instead of **"lib"** and clean project and check it..

**> Note: No need to build path for any third party library**

Comment: No there is no such directory But have RefrencedLibrary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17

Answer (score 1):

You need to create **libs** folder in your project and copy that jar file there. Then in eclipse, *right-click* on that jar file (which is in libs folder) select *Build Path* and then select *Add to Build Path*.

> **Remember:** if you are using a jar file in your *Android Library Project*, and associating that library project with your regular *UI
>   project*, it won't be enough. You must need to include that jar file
>   (as described above) in both of your projects (Android Library and UI
>   project) to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the jar to the Java Build Path?
Go to the Properties for the Project and select Java Build Path -> Libraries tab then add the external jar there.