# Having problems with importing dropbox and getting it to run?

Tags: java, android

I downloaded the dropbox sdk zip off the dropbox website, then imported the program into eclispe. Then i configured the build path and added the 2.2 jar file to run, theres no errors until I load up the aplication, when I ran it on the 1.5 emulator it gave me a Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception error, then when I ran it on the 2.2 emulator it gave me a at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021) error its not even letting the ap run, any ideas?

Comment: Post some of the problematic code (where logcat claims the error is occuring) and possibly the logcat logs.

Comment: 04-24 09:07:15.424: E/AndroidRuntime(450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 09:07:15.424: E/AndroidRuntime(450): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-24 09:07:15.424: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-24 09:07:15.424: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
04-24 09:07:15.424: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-24 09:07:15.424: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)

Comment: 04-24 09:13:48.954: W/dalvikvm(479): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown during Lcom/dropbox/android/sample/DBRoulette;.<clinit>
04-24 09:13:48.963: W/dalvikvm(479): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/dropbox/android/sample/DBRoulette;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue seems to come up when the library isn't properly loaded at runtime. I don't know much about it, but this question was asked and answered before. This may help: [Gson NoClassDefFoundError after ADT and SDK Tools update to v17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820675/gson-noclassdeffounderror-after-adt-and-sdk-tools-update-to-v17)

You can also try this: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Comment: Thanks I tried these, but nothing worked I cant find the problem