# NoClassDefFoundError: Urban Airship for Android Push

Tags: java, android, urbanairship.com

I've been trying to set up Urban Airship for days and it really stress me out.
Since their instruction isn't clear, I had to follow [this one](http://blog.jamesbaca.net/?p=235) to work through. 
However, I'm currently getting this errorLogs and trying to see if I can find some help.
Please any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.UAirship
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at com.app.android.NotifyMeApplication.onCreate(NotifyMeApplication.java:15)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:973)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3971)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:128)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
10-18 12:41:10.585: E/AndroidRuntime(11870):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I found a similar [qnestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672263/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-urbanairship-uairship) and answers,

-Remove all Android Library projects and external jars from the build path.

-Create a folder named 'libs' in your project.

-Place all external .jars in that folder, the ADT should now place them under 'Android Dependencies'.

-Re-import all your previous Android Library projects the normal way.

but it doesn't work for me.

This is Manifestfile, and the application runs fine if i remove the application name. 
But I need that in order to enable the push notification..

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name="com.app.android.NotifyMeApplication"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:enabled="true" >
```

NotifyMeApplication.java

```
package com.app.android;

import com.urbanairship.Logger;
import com.urbanairship.UAirship;
import com.urbanairship.push.PushManager;
import com.urbanairship.push.PushPreferences;

import android.app.Application;

public class NotifyMeApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
                UAirship.takeOff(this); // always needs to be called when starting an application

                // even though we call takeoff push notifications are disabled by default
                // you have to explicitly turn them on like so
                PushManager.enablePush();

                // let the push manager know about our intent receiver
                PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class); 
                // name must match broadcast receiver from step 7

                // set some preferences for sounds and vibration
                PushPreferences prefs = PushManager.shared().getPreferences();
                prefs.setSoundEnabled(true);
                prefs.setVibrateEnabled(true);

                // apid is a unique identifier for a particular device
                String lPushId = prefs.getPushId();
                Logger.info("My Application onCreate - App APID: " + lPushId);

    }
}
```

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't add some java code.

Comment: can you post the code that's throwing the error

Comment: yes of course.. but which class should i post? sorry i'm new to android/java..^^

Comment: start with the onCreate method of your NotifyMeApplication. That's where the error is coming from

Comment: I updated the code. could you please advise me kindly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get `NoClassDefFoundError` during Runtime, then I suspect you did not include them to work at runtime. You have to check the checkbox for each .jar like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, but now I get “Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1”

Comment: yes when i checked mark on the 3rd party jar file in the Order and Expert as your picture shows

Comment: just wondering..i don't have any Project under Project tab in Java Build Path. Do i need to add anything there?

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar