# Manually editing the Android project’s .classpath file

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

it seems like I can't resolve this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.UAirship that i posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959899/noclassdeffounderror-urban-airship-for-android-push).
I've been trying every possible ways that i found online but no luck..
However, I found another way that i want to try but i do not know how to do that because i 'm new to android.

Could someone direct me how to do this kindly?

**manually editing the Android project’s .classpath file with exported=”true”**

ps: if anyone knows how to fix the NoClassDefFoundError at Runtime, please let me know. Thank you

[image]

[image]

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name="com.app.android.NotifyMeApplication"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:enabled="true" >
```

Comment: Can you show Image from eclipse that shows JARs that you have added to your project, also tell your deployment Android version.

Comment: there you go..Thank you for reading my post

Comment: Amandeep, is there anything else you want to see???